# node, express and mysql on cloud9

Tags: node.js

i'm playing around on cloud9 with node.
i can get a very simple express app working
[image]

Now i want to add an sql database to this. 
however as soon as I install phpmyadmin [phpmyadmin-ctl install] the above program no longer works.
i suspect it has something to do with ports but can't find a way round it - anyone able to help?
thanks

Comment: Have you tried to ... change the port your app uses and see if it works?

Comment: thanks - i did try changing process.env.PORT to '3000' and then adding the port to the end of the URL cloud9 gives you but my index.html file didn't load

Comment: cloud9 says to use process.env.PORT but I think phpmyadmin is using the same port